# how to check if column value is not null then check next column using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT users.group_id, testtb.id 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN testtb on users.group_id =testtb.id 
where testtb.id is not null ORDER BY users.group_id
```

in my above query I want to use one more `where` condition(ie `where testtb.name is not null`)  if `testtb.id is not null`

Comment: Do you mean using this where clause: `where testtb.id is not null and testtb.name is not null`?

Comment: If my testtb.id is not null then testtb.name is not null should be work else testtb.name2 is not null should work

Comment: Ok, got you, check the [below answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29499323/3208640)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AND clause

```
    SELECT users.group_id, testtb.id FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN testtb on users.group_id =testtb.id 
    AND testtb.id is not null 
AND testtb.name is not null
    ORDER BY users.group_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.group_id, testtb.id 
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN testtb on users.group_id =testtb.id 
where testtb.id is not null 
and testtb.name is not null
ORDER BY users.group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [coalesce](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php):

```
SELECT users.group_id, testtb.id 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN testtb on users.group_id =testtb.id 
where testtb.id is not null 
AND COALESCE(testtb.name1,testtb.name2,testtb.name3) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY users.group_id
```